# Can I turn off automatic updates of snap apps?

Tags: updates, snap

I work in a remote workshop which has no internet connection. If I need to use my laptop while I am working, eg to look up datasheets, I tether it to my Android phone mobile data connection, but that is slow, unreliable and limited in how much data I can use.

I am on 18.04 (Kubuntu) at the moment and have removed snapd. But contemplating upgrading, it is clear that Ubuntu is moving more and more to auto-updating snaps.

So is it possible to turn off auto-updating for the entire snap sub-system?